# Probability that the sum of $k$ distinct integers selected from $1, 2, \dots, n$ is divisible by $n$

Tags: probability, combinatorial-number-theory

Would you please help me solve Problem 7 of Section 4.5, "Combinatorial Number Theory," in *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* Niven, Zuckerman, Montgomery, 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991:

> Let $n$ and $k$ be positive, relatively-prime integers with $n > k$.  Prove that if $k$ distinct integers are selected at random from $1, 2, \dots, n$, the probability that their sum is divisible by $n$ is $1/n$.

The authors describe three methods for solving combinatorial problems: (1) the pigeonhole principle, (2) the one-to-one correspondence procedure, in which elements in a finite set or between two sets are paired off to determine the number of elements, and (3) the inclusion-exclusion principle.  I know that the denominator of the probability fraction is $n \choose k$, so I tried (without success) to use the second method to count the number of desired outcomes to be $(n - 1)!/((n - k)! k!)$.

Because $n$ and $k$ are relatively prime, I know that $n \choose k$ is divisible by $n$.  In that case, numerical evidence suggests that the sum in question is uniformly distributed modulo $n$.  If I can prove that conjecture, I am done.

I found similar problems with particular values for $n$ and $k$, but the solutions do not help me solve this general case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of the numbers as integers modulo~$n$. Consider the map
$A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k\}\mapsto\{a_1+1,a_2+1,\ldots,a_k+1\}$. This adds $k$ modulo $n$ to the sum of the elements of $A$.

Comment: Can you explain more? How does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The exponential formula tells us that  the cycle index $Z(P_k)$ of the
unlabeled set operator

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{SET}$$

on $k$ slots has OGF

$$Z(P_k) = [w^k]
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} (-1)^{l-1} a_l \frac{w^l}{l}\right).$$

The desired probability is given by

$${n\choose k}^{-1} \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} 
\left. Z(P_k)
\left(\sum_{q=1}^n z^q\right)\right|_{z=\exp(2\pi ip/n)}.$$

This is

$${n\choose k}^{-1} \frac{1}{n} 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \left. [w^k]
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} (-1)^{l-1} \left(\sum_{q=1}^n z^{ql}\right)
\frac{w^l}{l}\right)\right|_{z=\exp(2\pi ip/n)}.$$

Evaluating the contribution for $p=0$ first we get

$${n\choose k}^{-1} \frac{1}{n} 
[w^k] \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} (-1)^{l-1} n
\frac{w^l}{l}\right)
\\ = {n\choose k}^{-1} \frac{1}{n} 
[w^k] \exp\left(n \log(1+w)\right)
\\ = {n\choose k}^{-1} \frac{1}{n} 
[w^k] (1+w)^n 
= {n\choose k}^{-1} \frac{1}{n} {n\choose k}
= \frac{1}{n}.$$

It remains to evaluate the contribution  from $1\le p\le n-1.$ Now for
these $p$ if $l$ is a multiple of $m = n/\gcd(p, n)$ we have

$$\sum_{q=1}^n \exp(2\pi ip/n)^{ql} = n.$$

We get zero otherwise. This yields for the remaining terms without the
scalar in front

$$\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} [w^k]
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} (-1)^{ml-1} n
\frac{w^{ml}}{ml} \right)
= \sum_{p=1}^{n-1} [w^k]
\exp\left(-\frac{n}{m} \sum_{l\ge 1} 
\frac{(-w)^{ml}}{l} \right)
\\ = \sum_{p=1}^{n-1} [w^k]
\exp\left(-\frac{n}{m}\log\frac{1}{1-(-w)^m}\right)
= \sum_{p=1}^{n-1} [w^k] (1-(-w)^{n/\gcd(p, n)})^{\gcd(p, n)}
\\ = \sum_{p=1}^{n-1} [w^k] (1+(-1)^{1+n/\gcd(p, n)}
w^{n/\gcd(p, n)})^{\gcd(p, n)}.$$

Using an Iverson bracket this becomes

$$\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} [[n/\gcd(p,n)|k]] \times
{\gcd(p, n)\choose k\gcd(p,n)/n} 
(-1)^{k\gcd(p,n)/n+k}.$$

Putting it all together we thus obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n} + (-1)^k
{n\choose k}^{-1} \frac{1}{n} 
\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} [[n/\gcd(p,n)|k]] \times
{\gcd(p, n)\choose k\gcd(p,n)/n} 
(-1)^{k\gcd(p,n)/n}.}$$

Note that $n/\gcd(p,n)$ is  a divisor of $n$ that is  at least two (we
would need $p=n$  to get $n/\gcd(p,n) = 1$ but  $p\lt n$).  This means
when $\gcd(k, n) =  1$ the Iverson bracket fails for  all $p$ and only
the first term remains, which is what we wanted to prove.

As a sanity check  we evaluate the formula when $k=n.$  The sum of the
one subset is $n(n+1)/2$ so we should get for the probability one when
$n$ is odd and zero when it is even. We find

$$\frac{1}{n} + (-1)^n
{n\choose n}^{-1} \frac{1}{n} 
\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} 
{\gcd(p, n)\choose \gcd(p,n)} 
(-1)^{\gcd(p,n)}
\\ = \frac{1}{n} + (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} 
(-1)^{\gcd(p,n)}
=  (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{p=1}^{n} 
(-1)^{\gcd(p,n)}
\\ = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{d|n} \sum_{\gcd(p,n) = d} (-1)^d
= (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{d|n} (-1)^d \sum_{\gcd(q,n/d) = 1} 1
\\ = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} (-1)^d \varphi(n/d).$$

We  evaluate  this  using   formal  Dirichlet  series,  starting  from
$\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) = n$ which yields

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}.$$

Furthermore we have

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s} = 
-\left(1-\frac{2}{2^s}\right)\zeta(s).$$

This means that

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^s} \sum_{d|n} (-1)^d \varphi(n/d)
= -\left(1-\frac{2}{2^s}\right) \zeta(s-1).$$

Now we have for $n$ even

$$- (-1)^n \frac{1}{n} [n^{-s}] \left(1-\frac{2}{2^s}\right) \zeta(s-1)
= - (-1)^n \frac{1}{n} (n - 2 [(n/2)^{-s}] \zeta(s-1)) 
\\ = - (-1)^n \frac{1}{n} (n - 2 \times n/2) = 0.$$

We obtain zero as required. On the other hand with $n$ odd we find

$$- (-1)^n \frac{1}{n} [n^{-s}] \left(1-\frac{2}{2^s}\right) \zeta(s-1)
= - (-1)^n \frac{1}{n} [n^{-s}] \zeta(s-1)
\\ = - (-1)^n \frac{1}{n} \times n = 1,$$

again as  required. This  concludes the sanity  check. and  indeed the
entire argument.

**Remark.** Some  of this  material is duplicate  where I  have not
found the links however.

**Addendum.** The sum can be simplified. Starting with

$$\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} [[n/\gcd(p, n)|k]]
\times {\gcd(p,n) \choose k \gcd(p,n)/n} (-1)^{k\gcd(p,n)/n}.$$

With the GCD being $d$ we get

$$\sum_{d|n \wedge d \lt n}
\sum_{\gcd(p,n) = d}
[[n/d|k]]
\times {d \choose kd/n} (-1)^{kd/n}.$$

where we retain $1\le p\le n-1$. This is

$$\sum_{d|n \wedge d \lt n}
\sum_{\gcd(q,n/d) = 1}
[[n/d|k]]
\times {d \choose kd/n} (-1)^{kd/n}
\\ = \sum_{f|k \wedge f\gt 1} \sum_{d|n \wedge d \lt n}
\sum_{\gcd(q,n/d) = 1, n/d=f}
{d \choose kd/n} (-1)^{kd/n}$$

Here we have $1\le qd\le n-1$ but since $d\lt n$ we may actually use
$1\le qd\le n$ to obtain (this is because $\gcd(n/d,n/d) = n/d \gt 1$)

$$\sum_{d|n \wedge d \lt n \wedge n/d|k}
\sum_{\gcd(q,n/d) = 1}
{d \choose kd/n} (-1)^{kd/n}
= \sum_{d|n \wedge d \lt n \wedge n/d|k}
\varphi(n/d) {d \choose kd/n} (-1)^{kd/n}
\\ = \sum_{d|n \wedge d \gt 1 \wedge d|k}
\varphi(d) {n/d \choose k/d} (-1)^{k/d}
= \sum_{d|\gcd(n,k) \wedge d \gt 1}
\varphi(d) {n/d \choose k/d} (-1)^{k/d}.$$

Merge this into the boxed formula to get

$$\frac{1}{n} +
(-1)^k {n\choose k}^{-1}
\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{d|\gcd(n,k) \wedge d \gt 1}
\varphi(d) {n/d \choose k/d} (-1)^{k/d}$$

or alternatively

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
(-1)^k {n\choose k}^{-1}
\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{d|\gcd(n,k)}
\varphi(d) {n/d \choose k/d} (-1)^{k/d}.}$$