# Reference request for a classic result in additive combinatorics.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime number and $[p-1]=\{1, 2, \ldots, p-1\}$.
The following proposition is proved: (but I cannot find out where)

> Proposition: The non-empty subset sums of $[p-1]$ are equally distributed
> $\pmod{p}$.

In other words, if $N(a)$ denotes the number of subset sums which are $\equiv a\pmod{p}$ then $N(a)=\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$, for every integer $0\le a\le p-1$.
I know that there is a proof using $p$-th roots of unity (Complex numbers  $z$, such that $z^p=1$), but I cannot find out *where* this is proved.

Can anybody give me some reference where I can find a proof of the proposition using complex numbers? I would prefer if possible some survey which also touches other similar topics and the techniques are based in complex numbers.

Comment: Are you sure you want to exclude the sets with sum $0$?  After all, $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\frac {2^{p-1}-1}p$ does not equal $2^{p-1}-1$

Comment: @lulu you are right this was a mistake. I also want the sum which is is 0 modp. I made an edit

Comment: No worries. $\quad$

Comment: Note:  a suitable modification of the argument given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417918/probability-that-the-sum-of-k-distinct-integers-selected-from-1-2-dots-n) should get the job done.  Note that you can always pretend that $0$ is in your set for translation purposes.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432679/reference-request-for-a-result-in-additive-combinatorics